# IS there concrete vector class in UWP C++ Winrt

Tags: collections, uwp, idl

There are various CONCRETE collection classes under c++\Cx platform.

But when i look at UWP API , all i see under collections are interfaces.
This is very confusing.

I cant use standard c++ collections to bind to xaml and idl for gui.

But the only collections defined in UWp are interfaces.

I am sure am missing something very very obvious any help appreciated. Before i have to go and implement an IObservable Vector when all i really need is simple ANSI C array.

Its quite difficult looking at an API set from the perceptive of interfaces to implement as opposed to the norm of concrete classes to consume.

I am just trying to find a concrete collection type i can use in IDL, so that other runtime class can acess, example xaml. But cant find any unless i implement an interface.

Comment: Is this what you were looking for:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/collections-c-cx

Comment: thanks for the tip. dont think i can use Platform::Collections  in cpp/winrt. But winrt::Windows.Foundation.Collections  which i can use, seems to have only interfaces no concrete  types. Which leaves me wondering just what is the range of collections i can use in cppwinrt that IDL will also be happy with .

Comment: And i have also gone to use Observable_vector from winrt PhotoEditor sample, but that is giving me abi_GetTrustLevel not implemented by type T during build, which is my data type i want usable with RunTime class.

Comment: Are you looking for some collection class such as [`ObservableCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: The UWP API Windows.Foundation.Collections document listing the interfaces refers specifically (in the Remarks section) to that article linked by @Muzib, which prescribes Platform::Collections implementations.  What makes you think you cannot use them?

Comment: _I am just trying to find a concrete collection type i can use in IDL_
Other than simple data types, you should not use concrete types in IDL.

Comment: Thanks very much for feedback, i made error in tag for this question, added correct tag c++-Winrt, and updated the question based on your helpull feedback.

Comment: You haven't updated the question. You asked a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51890703/1889329), that's essentially the same. You should have clicked the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51851581/edit) link instead.