# Scope of Collections in Winrt And PhotoEditor example

Tags: collections, uwp, c++-winrt

1. Winrt::Windows::Foundation::Collection only has interfaces no concrete collection type.
2. I have been told to use Platorm::Collections, but not sure how you get to that from Winrt::Windows::?????. I thought its only for C++/Cx

3.I have copied and used the Observable_Vector in PhotoEditor sample but am getting error on build saying my type in vector does not implement GetTrustLevel().

4. If i cannot use Platform::Collections in WInrt, that means currently there is only one example of how to use collections with Winrt (PhotoEditor) and that will also mean onyl concrete collection in Winrt is the Observable_Vector in phtotEditor.

Need help to clarify the scope of collection in c++-Winrt.
And also any help as to why am Getting Trust level error when using same Observable_vector from PhotoEditor.

Thanks

Comment: Ok i can now build my project thats using Observable_Vector from photoeditor, cause i used Observable_Vector<MyType>. Got trust error previously cause i was doing Observable_Vector<IInspectable>. Some of the new windows code code seems to defy logic. In PhotoEditor i was expecting Observable_Vector<Photo>, but no it was Observable_Vector<IInspectable>. An explanation would help though.

Comment: It's not immediately clear, what the question is asking for. [XAML items controls; bind to a C++/WinRT collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/binding-collection) has information on observable collections as used in the Windows Runtime. That information might be helpful in improving this question.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not have to implement your own collections. C++/WinRT provides a set of helper functions for creating a variety of common generic collection types. For example:

```cpp
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Foundation::Collections;

int main()
{
    IVector<int> a = single_threaded_vector<int>({ 1,2,3 });
    IObservableMap<hstring, int> b = single_threaded_observable_map<hstring, int>();
}
```

There is also support for creating custom collections. I described some of those options here:

https://kennykerr.ca/2018/05/12/cppwinrt-creating-collections-simply-efficiently/

Comment: Thanks very much that clears up my understanding of the scope of collections in winrt, at least as far as vectors and maps go.  Please where can i can any documentration for  single_threaded_vector and single_threaded_observable_map and generally documentation for that part of winrt where these 2 api belong. For example i was expecting to see them here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/winrt  Thanks much for reviving embedded windows c++

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've asked our doc writer to add these.